# How can I get my organization to stop using email for everything

Tags: communication, email

My organization uses email among a few departments to handle several processes, including user support and HR actions. This causes lots of messages and replies to go to many people who may not be involved.

I have created a web-based system to manage the HR processes. The current practice is to  fill out Word documents and emailing them around until all the steps are complete. The new system I built has been waiting a while for review and acceptance. It can send emails when needed, to only the people who need to be notified.

Similarly, I have built a support issue tracking system which would dramatically reduce the amount of email, but it has not been reviewed yet. Is there a reason that we continue to use email when a better alternative exists?

Comment: Did you ask the people involved what they wanted from this system before you built it?

Comment: @DJClayworth Faster email?

Comment: -1 This seems intrinsically dependent on the details (which aren't given) of the locale in question, and I don't see how SE commenters can answer this successfully.

Comment: How do you know your system is a better alternative? It may be, or it may not be. "but it has not been reviewed yet." To me, it seems like you're going things backward. The user-research and the the usability testing should have come before you've built the software, not after.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Wouldn't almost any web app be better than dozens of emails a day reaching dozens of people, most of whom are not involved?

Comment: Don Norman was saying that if you have a clear idea of what is needed and how to do it, asking users is a waste of time and probably misleading. Aren't we supposed to know how to build software? I would ask experts for domain knowledge, not how to do my job.

Comment: @BreakingGnus, Yes, in theory, but you're not taking into account the reasons of the individuals. There could be a thousand and one different reasons people prefer to use email instead of your tool. In any case, your tool hasn't even been deployed to everyone yet? Right? If that's the case, the usability of your tool doesn't matter. What precisely matters right now is the reasoning of the person who assigned you this job in the first place. You need to speak to them, not us.

Comment: "Wouldn't almost any web app be better..." No, in many, many cases. *Did* you get advance buy-in prior to making this tool? Did you get assigned this job by a manager? What process generated the work order? Who exactly has the job of reviewing and accepting the tool?

Comment: One decisionmaker has retired, another is deceased. Still, dealing with lots of email noise is worth doing something about, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need departmental buy in, changing practices is a difficult and tedious process. Most of the work is going to be put in by you and the other process owners such as HR.

If you have HRs buy in, you need to tell them to ignore all requests over email if they should have been made using your web system. You have to get the HR department to agree to answer all emails that should have gone through the system with:

"Hi X,
Please submit that request through the web system so we can properly track and complete that."

The same goes for your support tracking issue, as an IT person I get walk ups, phone calls, and emails all day long. I always respond with something akin to:

"Sounds great, I'm working on something else right now can you submit that as a ticket so I don't forget about it."

Comment: The last bit is not going to fly - asking a manager, who is about to give an important presentation, walking in with a non-functional notebook to the internal IT department to go fill a ticket is a surefire way to get the system scrapped in a record time. What you do at that time is do the work && create the ticket at the same time or post fact...

Comment: There are exceptions to every rule, obviously if there is an actual emergency you overlook it. However it's important to enforce it as often as possible, otherwise people will think their mediocre inconvenience is an emergency.

Answer (score 9):

> How can I get my organization to stop using email for everything

If you have the authority you just make it mandatory like any job tracking system.

If you don't have the authority, you convince whoever does to make it mandatory. Usually this would be the people who got you to build it in the first place.

Comment: This! This is precisely it! You have to either have a majority of users wanting to use the system or have a major decision maker wanting to use the system. (bottom-up or top-down)

Comment: @mishan Could a minor decisionmaker do it? (middle-out?)

Comment: Not really, unless it's mandatory, inertia will prevent people using it, some will, some won't for a while, then probably eventually no one will because it's complicates things if only a subset use it.

Comment: My father said, "Business and government function mainly by inertia."

Answer (score 1):

Kudos on your enthusiasm to get a problem solved.  But there are bigger issue to consider.

1. Was the project officially sanctioned between IT and any business stakeholders?
2. Are you actually working in an IT role as a web developer?
3. HR handles a lot of documents that, by their nature, need to be secure.  How's that going to work?
4. What happens if you leave the company?  What would an off-the-shelf enterprise software package cost, to make sure that whatever they put in place is maintainable in the long term?
5. Is it a high-availability system?
6. Who "owns" it, and will take the hit if things aren't working right?
7. Who's supporting it when a user needs to use the system at 2:00AM (or when you're on vacation) and things aren't working correctly?
8. Has there been an official allocation for network traffic, DNS, disk space, and other server resources?  How fast will those resource needs grow, over time?
9. How do bugs get reported and fixed?
10. Who's doing QA?
11. Did you build with tools that are supportable over the long term?
12. Roles.  How are roles set up within the application so that everybody doesn't have rights to use all features?
13. Can authentication and authorization be easily administered by the IT infrastructure team against a current authorization store, or does everyone have to use a separate login/password to access it?
14. Has it been hardened against hacking?  (SQL injection, denial of service)

*These* are the questions that need answering before "how can I get my company to stop using email for everything", with emphasis on using your solution.

Comment: These are excellent questions, I wish I could post an "Answer". The organization is under 500 people and the system is a very basic intranet. Re: #3 - it will be more secure than passing Word docs around in email. For the others - I am in the IT dept and it is basically for IT and another dept. It is a small shop, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of change, top-down and bottom-up.

Top-down is a mandate, your boss (or someone above them) issues a directive.  If you don't follow it, expect to see something negative on your review.

Bottom-up is a grass roots effort, it is harder to do, but it is basically having enough of the workers on board that they start doing it.  Management basically steps in to agree.  The advent of personal computers in the work place is an example of a bottom-up change.  People brought their own computers in to work initially.  Management then blessed the idea of them in the workplace.

You're not attempting either approach.  In short you're going to create a problem, but only for yourself.  Figure out which approach you need to take, and get people on board with that.

Comment: Ok. But is there a place for someone from "outside" to suggest change, and for people in the middle to ask for it? Must we be rigid?

Comment: @BreakingGnus My comments come from a study I read a long time about about how successful changes are (mostly) executed.  I am sure there are other ways changes can happen, but they didn't warrant enough success to get a mention.  I suggest you figure out a way to get your change re-cast to fit a successful pattern.  Trying to make a success in a new way is much, much harder.  Maybe you can foster grass root support, but a change like this probably means you need to find a supporter in upper management; because, it's probably an easier path, considering the problem.